# Lotus Notes "Design Synopsis"

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-designer

Can the synopsis table help me find every place (form, script, formula, outlines, navigator...) where I use a specific view?

For example I want to find every place where i have used view1.

Is there a method that would allow me to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in Designer the search menu: "Search / File...". Set the scope to "Enclosing projects" and search for your view name.

It shows you in all design elements where this name is used.

*Example:* search for view "$VIMPeople" in mail database

[image]

shows you where the view is used

[image]

Comment: sorry, i haven't specify that i use lotus notes 6.5.6 and there isn't search menù.

Comment: I see. But, I am pretty sure that you as a curious Notes Domino developer have a test environment with Designer 8.5 or higher. Why not create a design-only-copy of database and explore it there?

Comment: Otherwise, you can use the Synopsis. Just select all design elements at "Application/Design Synopsis..." and all Formula, LotusScript and Java code will be presented. As you on version 6.5.6 you don't have to worry that modern design elements like XPages are not listed in Synopsis.

Comment: Really I have only tried v.8.5.
Now i will download it from ibm site and study it !
yes, i'm curious!

Comment: Good decision! There is a lot to explore - have fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to stay on a more than 10 years old version (6.5 was released in September 2003), you could get Teamstudio Configurator, a great tool that allow you to do searches (and also replace code) in your Notes databases. It is very handy.
I blogged about it (as well as some othe rtools I think every Notes developer should have on their computer) here: http://blog.texasswede.com/my-favorite-tools/

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used the old Designer client, but my recollection is that the synopsis wasn't searchable after you generate it, so what I used to do is generate it, then copy all the output to the clipboard and paste it into a text editor where I could search for whatever I needed to find.

Comment: The output to a either a document or database is searchable. For a document, simply use Ctrl-F to call up the 'find' function, or full text index the DB is use that option.

Comment: Yes, it's searchable now.